# CSS Class names not matching when using Beautiful Soup vs CSS selector on the webpage

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner in Python and currently learning how to webscrape using [this book](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e).

I'm trying to write a program where I can google search something and have the program that opens the first five links that turn up in the search results. The goal is to find the name of a class that's directly above the `<a href='link'>` tag.

The **tags** look like this:

```
<div class = placeholder>

<a href = link>
```

However, when I'm trying to select a css selector, the selector doesn't turn up when I use beautiful soup, and I have to manually search for it by copying and pasting the html and css parsed by beautiful soup. Why is this happening?

**Code:**

```py
res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q=beautiful+soup')

res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

linkElems = soup.select(".kCrYT a")

numLinks = min(5, len(linkElems))

for i in range(numLinks):

webbrowser.open('https://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

The css selector I manually found by running "soup" is `kCrYT`, but when opening up in chrome, the class name is `r`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you considered to use the selector `.r > a:nth-child(-n+5)` to get the first five search result elements?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I did try it out and found that .kCrYT > a:nth-child(1) would get all of the href tags.

Comment: Not a problem, now you have two ways to proceed: **A)** Use a cycle to get the first five elements, as you need **B)** Try to replace `a:nth-child(1)` with `a:nth-child(-n+5)`, then if it works you won't need a cycle

Comment: I went ahead and used the css selector method. It's incredibly useful; thanks!